# Query executes slower when placed inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in which i also have used a function.It executes in less than one minute.But when i put the same query inside a stored procedure and call,it takes near about 8 minutes.Why so? i am not able to understand why its happening and why its taking time so much of time?I think Most of the time is consumed when i call the function from my stored procedure.
Here is my query:-

```
 SELECT  et.X,et.Y,et.EquipID as ID,e.EquipmentName as Name,e.EquipmentNo,eg.EquipGroup as 'Fleet_Name',et.SpeedOfTheVehicle as Speed,et.IgnitionStatus,convert(varchar,et.SignalDateTime) as SignalDateTime,
et.DriverID,case d.DriverName when '' then 'Name' else d.DriverName end as DriverName,
case isnull(d.EmployeeNo,'') when '' then '0' else d.EmployeeNo end  as DriverNo,
case isnull(d.LicenseNo,'') when '' then '0' else d.LicenseNo end as LicenseNo,
dbo.GetFilterColorStatusOfEquipment(et.SignalDateTime,et.SpeedOfTheVehicle,(SELECT COUNT(J.JobId) FROM tbl_Notification J 
               inner JOIN tbl_NotificationAssign JN ON  JN.NotificationNo =J.NotificationNo
               inner JOIN dbo.tbl_CustomStatus JS ON JS.CustomStatusID=J.CustomStatusID 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SystemStatus ss ON ss.SystemStatusID=JS.SystemStatusID
               WHERE JN.DriverID=et.DriverID AND ss.SystemStatusID !=9),et.IgnitionStatus) as FilterStatus,
e.SerialNo,e.GPSIMIENO,'Equipment' TYPE,etr.Vector,si.ImgPath as 'Icon',et.Address,
etr.EquipTypeID,si.StatusTypeID,ss.SystemStatusCode
from dbo.tbl_Equipment e 
left outer join dbo.tbl_EquipmentTrack et  on et.EquipID=e.EquipID 
left outer join dbo.tbl_DriverMaster d on et.DriverID=d.DriverID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_EquipmentGroup eg ON eg.EquipGroupID=e.EquipGroupID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_EquipmentType etr ON etr.EquipTypeID=eg.EquipTypeID
full outer join dbo.tbl_StatusIMG si on etr.EquipTypeID=si.NotificationType and si.StatusTypeID=2 
full outer join dbo.tbl_SystemStatus ss on ss.SystemStatusID=si.SystemStatusID

where 
et.X is not null and et.Y is not null and e.EquipmentName is not null AND e.Available='Available'
AND ((dbo.GetFilterStatusOfEquipment(et.SignalDateTime,et.SpeedOfTheVehicle,(SELECT COUNT(J.JobId) FROM tbl_Notification J 
               inner JOIN tbl_NotificationAssign JN ON  JN.NotificationNo =J.NotificationNo
               inner JOIN dbo.tbl_CustomStatus JS ON JS.CustomStatusID=J.CustomStatusID 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SystemStatus ss ON ss.SystemStatusID=JS.SystemStatusID
               WHERE JN.DriverID=et.DriverID AND ss.SystemStatusID !=9),et.IgnitionStatus) in (select val from dbo.split(@filter,','))) OR
(@filter='*' or @filter=''))
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you; http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the statement and report back, pls

Comment: This is almost always to do with parameter sniffing.

Comment: in a glance i notice  dbo.GetFilterStatusOfEquipment UDF .

DEATH BY UDF

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx

Comment: There is a LOT of low hanging fruit to improve performance here. You have several scalar functions as noted above, you have a split function which may or may not be a bad for performance, you have a LOT of nonSARGable predicates in your where clauses and you are hitting the several of the same base tables repeatedly. Last but not least, you have a column in your select statement which is a subquery. This is also very bad for performance. To make faster it will require a total rewrite.

Comment: applied  OPTION (RECOMPILE) also.still query takes the same time as previous.